# iphone singleton instance in the LocateMe sample code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton

Can anyone explain why a singleton instance of the MyCLController class is used in the sample iphone app LocateMe found [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LocateMe/index.html)

as well as the overriding of retain, retainCount, release, and autorelease?  Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because only a single instance of MyCLController is ever needed in the application.

The singleton implementation in that example is the über-defensive pattern.  It overrides all of the other methods to prevent you from ever potentially deallocating the instance.

Personally, I never go through such hoops (and the documentation will be changed in the future), preferring to do a dead simple +sharedInstance method instead:

```
+ sharedInstance
{
    static id sharedInstance = nil;
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [self alloc];
        sharedInstance = [sharedInstance init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

(1) Yes, I broke up the alloc/init on purpose.   It lets anything in the -init method call +sharedInstance without a problem.

(2) No, this doesn't deal with multithreading.  For that, I use GCD's dispatch_once().  On the iPhone, you would need a slightly different pattern.  @synchronized() works, but is overhead.

One of the reason's why I find the über-defensive pattern to be disconcerting is because, frankly, if you have a singleton class and you are causing it to be deallocated through over-release, your code is broken and that kind of bug should not be obscured.  If anything, the code should fail catastrophically.    As well, there are a number of situations where a singleton class may also be valid with individual instances, too.